# Possible to shadow/override a SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, overriding

Is there any built in way, in SQL Server, to override an existing stored procedure for a single transaction?

Say I have a stored procedure

```
prc_GetValidUsers
@param1 int
 ...
 INSERT INTO *
........prc_GetIdFromString param3
...
...
```

Is it possible for a single transaction, to redefine what `prc_GetIdFromString` to be something else? Or is it impossible to do this?

Comment: why don't you use a parameter in your sp an create a path to the other table depending on that parameter?

Comment: I'm trying to unit test the prc_GetValidUsers, but the prc_GetIdFromString is a giant function that references many tables, and is part of legacy code.  As it's for testing purposes, I don't want to put in any code just for the tests, but I also don't want to create data in all those tables for testing a small function.

Comment: In test, create dbo.prc_TestGetIdFromString, remove all extra code.  Call this SP instead.  There is no object oriented concepts like over riding in the database.  If you want to be fancy, create a schema [test].  Then you can call test.prc_GetIdFromString instead of dbo.prc_TestGetIdFromString ...

Comment: Personally I never create anything at all complex in a proc without a test parameter and then rollback if it is set to test mode. No point puttin gbad data ina database while you are making the proc work or changing it.  If you make it the last parameter and give it a default value of 0 (non-test mode) then you don't even have to change any existing proc calls in the application.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2005, or later, you could use a [SYNONYM](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177544%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) to point at the correct code at run time.  This would require moving the existing code to an SP with a new name - so the `SYNONYM` could have the name of the original SP (so that everything that referenced the original SP would not need to be changed).  You'd also create another SP that performed the reduced functionality that you want.  The `SYNONYM` could then be pointed at the SP that you want to run.